# Is there evidence that women who said they were sexually assaulted by Trump lied for money?

Tags: united-states, politics, donald-trump, sexual-abuse, media

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump_sexual_misconduct_allegations), there are at least 19 women who have accused Trump of sexual assault or harassment. Trump has recently [claimed](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2018/09/26/trump-set-to-speak-on-kavanaugh-un-general-assembly-at-press-conference.html):

> I was accused by, I believe it was four women," Trump said. "I was accused by four or five women who got paid a lot of money to make up stories about me. We caught them and the mainstream media refused to put it on television ... So I've had numerous accusations about me."

The part about being accused by only four women seems misleading. But is there any evidence for the other parts of the claim? Have Trump or his associates "caught" women lying about being sexually assaulted by Trump for money? And if there is evidence, has the mainstream media refused to report on it?

Comment: Since it's something he believes could have been reported, then either he or outlets like Fox would have had no reason to not report it. Because of that, then either no women were caught lying or some were but it's not something that is publicly available(perhaps protected by an [NDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement) or similar). Either way, this question seems like it can't be answered unless he provides any amount of information about it.

Comment: @LangLangC Yes, that part seems untrue, because there are more than 4 women who have accused Trump of sexual assault. See eg this [list](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/trump-sexual-assault-allegations-claims-women-how-many-groping-accused-us-president-a8091581.html) which has 15 or so women who accuse him of sexual assault, and a number who accuse him of sexual harassment.

Comment: @Giter It could be that the first part of the claim is true (women lied for money), but not the second (it was actually reported on; though possibly not to the extend that Trump would have liked), which would allow for a good answer. There could also be reliable but non-mainstream media sources supporting the claim. A reasonable answer could also point to a reliable source fact-checking the claim and concluding that there is no evidence for this. We have a number of other questions where Trump claimed something without any evidence, and I don't think that questions like that are unanswerable.

Comment: A *not unreasonable* interpretation of Trump's claim is "There are 4 or 5 women who were paid to claim sexual harassment", and that it simply doesn't address the other accusations listed on Wikipedia, rather than interpreting it as claiming there were only 4 or 5 accusations and all of them were paid for it. I think it's likely that the specific phrasing chosen intentionally tries to *imply* all accusations were invalid, but I don't think there's an airtight case that the "four women" part was strictly a lie.